# Random numbers without duplicates

Tags: haskell, random, unique

Simulating a lottery of 6 numbers chosen from 40, I want to create a list of numbers in Haskell using the system random generator but eliminate duplicates, which often arise.

If I have the following:

```
import System.Random

main :: IO ()
main = do
  rs <- forM [1..6] $ \_x -> randomRIO (1, 40) :: (IO Int)
  print rs
```

this is halfway. But how do I filter out duplicates? It seems to me I need a while loop of some sort to construct a list filtering elements that are already in the list until the list is the required size. If I can generate an infinite list of random numbers and filter it inside the IO monad I am sure that would work, but I do not know how to approach this. It seems while loops are generally deprecated in Haskell, so I am uncertain of the true Haskeller's way here. Is this a legitimate use case for a while loop, and if so, how does one do that?

Comment: Will you use all the values?

Comment: What is the goal? `System.Random` isn't secure and doesn't even give good random values.

Comment: Yes, I want a list (or set) of six numbers with no duplicates, as in a lottery where numbered balls are drawn from a set.

Comment: The goal is to learn how to build a list monadically using filtering. It's a raw newbie question. Also, if System. Random does not give good values, what does?

Comment: See the tf-random package for one example.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson the RNG in `System.Random` is good enough for this task. Also `System.Random` includes the `RandomGen` class, allowing you to write a instance for every RNG you can imagine. Relative to Occam's razor, `System.Random` is the base module you should use every time, when you handle random numbers.

Comment: @Vektorweg I couldn't disagree more.   `System.Random` is about only useful for education or quick prototypes.  For example, in property checking it can result in tests erroneously passing even when a large portion of the domain would fail.  The `RandomGen` class fails in at least three ways 1) It can only generate `Int`s 2) Users must break abstraction to create generators 3) Generators can't fail without exceptions.  For these reasons `System.Random` is the module you should avoid every time you handle random numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The function you are looking for is [`nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) from `Data.List`, to filter dublicates.

```
import Data.List
import System.Random

main = do
    g <- newStdGen
    print . take 6 . nub $ (randomRs (1,40) g :: [Int])
```

Comment: Nice. Because it returns an (infinite) _pseudo_-random list, `randomRs` can be pure, and you can use it with `nub`. If you need _real_ random values (e.g. from `/dev/urandom`) you will still need a kind of monadic `while` or `until`, as the question-asker was trying.

Comment: @HansLub I can't imagine a situation where you need *real* random values.

Comment: I read the question more like: how does one gather a list of results of monadic actions, until the list satisfies some criterion. I see that you give an example in your _other_ answer. Nice again!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using a library, then install the [random-shuffle package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle) and use it like this:

```
import System.Random.Shuffle
import Control.Monad.Random

main1 = do
  perm <- evalRandIO $ shuffleM [1..10]
  print perm
```

If you want to see how to implement a naive Fischer-Yates shuffle using lists in Haskell, have a look at this code:

```
  shuffle2 xs g = go [] g (length xs) xs
    where
      go perm g n avail
        | n == 0    = (perm,g)
        | otherwise = let (i, g') = randomR (0,n-1) g
                          a = avail !! i
                          -- can also use splitAt to define avail':
                          avail' = take i avail ++ drop (i+1) avail
                      in go (a:perm) g' (n-1) avail'

  main = do
    perm <- evalRandIO $ liftRand $ shuffle2 [1..10]
    print perm
```

The parameters to the `go` helper function are:

- `perm` - the constructed permutation so far
- `g` - the current generator value
- `n` - the length of the available items
- `avail` - the available items - i.e. items not yet selected to be part of the permutation

`go` simply adds a random element from `avail` to the permutation being constructed and recursively calls itself with the new avail list and new generator.

To only draw `k` random elements from `xs`, just start `go` at `k` instead of `length xs`:

```
shuffle2 xs k g = go [] g k xs
  ...
```

You could also use a temporary array (in the ST or IO monad) to implement a Fischer-Yates type algorithm. The `shuffleM` function in `random-shuffle` uses a yet completely different approach which you might find interesting.

*Update:* Here is an example of using an ST-array in a F-Y style algorithm:

```
import Control.Monad.Random
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST (runST, ST)

shuffle3 :: RandomGen g => Int -> g -> ([Int], g)
shuffle3 n g0 = runST $ do
  arr <- newListArray (1,n) [1..n] :: ST s (STUArray s Int Int)
  let step g i = do let (j,g') = randomR (1,n) g
                    -- swap i and j
                    a <- readArray arr i
                    b <- readArray arr j
                    writeArray arr j a
                    writeArray arr i b
                    return g'
  g' <- foldM step g0 [1..n]
  perm <- getElems arr
  return (perm, g')

main = do
  perm <- evalRandIO $ liftRand $ shuffle3 20
  print perm
```

Comment: Instead of `take i avail ++ drop (i+1) avail` use `splitAt i avail`.

Comment: Suppose we would have to draw 6 numbers between 0 and 100000. Would you still randomly shuffle `[1..100000]` and then take the first 6?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [Fisher Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) in C++ with a decent random number generator to great success.  This approach is very efficient if you are willing to allocate an array for holding numbers 1 to 40.

Comment: The question is how to do this in Haskell specifically.

Comment: What I think is important is that the Fisher Yates Shuffle won't produce duplicates, so it a good algorithm to use (if possible in Haskell). :)

Answer (score 1):

Going the strict IO way requires to break down `nub`, bringing the condition into the tail recursion.

```
import System.Random

randsf :: (Eq a, Num a, Random a) => [a] -> IO [a]
randsf rs
    | length rs > 6 = return rs
    | otherwise = do
        r <- randomRIO (1,40)
        if elem r rs 
            then randsf rs 
            else randsf (r:rs)

main = do
    rs <- randsf [] :: IO [Int]
    print rs
```

If you know what you do `unsafeInterleaveIO` from `System.IO.Unsafe` can be handy, allowing you to generate lazy lists from IO. Functions like `getContents` work this way.

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Random
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Data.List

rands :: (Eq a, Num a, Random a) => IO [a]
rands = do 
    r <- randomRIO (1,40)
    unsafeInterleaveIO $ liftM (r:) rands

main = do 
    rs <- rands :: IO [Int]
    print . take 6 $ nub rs
```

Answer (score 0):

You commented:

> The goal is to learn how to build a list monadically using filtering. It's a raw newbie question

Maybe you should change the question title then! Anyways, this is quite a common task. I usually define a combinator with a general monadic type that does what I want, give it a descriptive name (which I didn't quite succeed in here :-) and then use it, like below

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Random

-- | 'myUntil': accumulate a list with unique action results until the list 
-- satisfies a test                                                        
myUntil :: (Monad m, Eq a) => ([a] -> Bool) -> m a -> m [a]
myUntil test action = myUntil' test [] action where
  myUntil' test resultSoFar action = do
     if test resultSoFar then
       return resultSoFar
     else do
       x <- action
       let newResults = if x `elem` resultSoFar then resultSoFar 
                                                else resultSoFar ++ [x] -- x:resultSoFar
       myUntil' test newResults action

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let enough xs = length xs == 6
        drawNumber  = randomRIO (0, 40::Int)
    numbers <- myUntil enough drawNumber
    print numbers
```

NB: this is not the optimal way to get your 6 distinct numbers, but meant as an example how to, *in general*,  build a list monadically using a filter that works on *the entire list*

It is in essence the same as Vektorweg's longest answer, but uses a combinator with a much more general type (which is the way I like to do it, which may be more useful for you, given your comment at the top of this answer)